# c#: Delete a word from a .txt file

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program to delete one word from a text file, but on running it nothing is deleted from the text file.

Here's my code:

```
string fileName = "\\\\itworks\\txt\\dlist_file.txt";
var selectedText = Objectt;
var selectedTextString = selectedText.ToString();

var unselectedLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(l => l != selectedTextString);

File.WriteAllLines(fileName, unselectedLines);
```

The text file `dlist_file.txt` looks like this

```
hello
test
yeah
```

Comment: What word do you need to remove from your text file?

Comment: for example the word "test"

Comment: what is happening? what is wrong? what else have you attempted?

Comment: What's the problem with your current code? Is it that you want it by word and not by line?

Comment: My current code is still not working

Comment: So what is the question? When you run the code, what happens? What does the output file look like?  Please clearly define "not working".

Comment: My code just do nothing.

Comment: Try adding `.ToArray` at the end of your line selection, ie: `File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(l => l != selectedTextString).ToArray();`

Comment: When you run it, does an output file get created? If so, what text does that contain?

Comment: .ToArray(); brings no different.

Comment: The text file is there before I start my program. But my program changes nothing.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions, or it just runs quietly without effects? Can you make some breakpoints to see what's inside `selectedTextString` and what's inside `unselectedLines` after filtering out?

Comment: Dann fragst Du die falschen Leute ;-) -> This means you are asking the wrong guys

Comment: Your problem is describing your problem. Whatever it is, the solution is likely trival. (And yes yes, ignore the current answers....)

Answer (score 0):

You code has a few issues.

1) It looks like you are reading from a network drive.   ("\\itworks\txt\dlist_file.txt";). Make sure you have access to the file.

2) This line does not make sense.  var selectedText = Objectt; (What is Objectt? why does it have to be an object, not a string?) If you are trying to define a filter, you can define it as a string array instead.

3) This line is not necessary. (var selectedTextString = selectedText.ToString());

4) Your intention is correct in this line. But it will not work because of the way you have defined your selectedTextString variable (var unselectedLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(l => l != selectedTextString);)

5) Here you are overwriting your original file. Why not create a new file instead and compare your existing file with the new one?
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, unselectedLines);

Can you correct these issues by yourself? If not, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing functionally wrong with the code except perhaps this line:

`var selectedText = Objectt;`

I copied and pasted the code into LINQPad and got the desired results.

```
string fileName = @"C:\temp\Homework.txt";
var selectedText = "test";
var selectedTextString = selectedText.ToString();

var unselectedLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(l => l != selectedTextString);

File.WriteAllLines(fileName, unselectedLines);

foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is the content of my file:

```
hello
test
yeah
```

Here is the output:

```
hello 
yeah
```

Perhaps there is a permissions issue or something similar. I would expect you to get an exception when trying to write the file if that were the case though.

Comment: tanks for your answer. My Visual Studio can´t start the program, the mistake is "Dump();":

Comment: That is a function specific to LINQPad. I changed the code spit out each line to the console instead.